# How do I go from box editing back to editing the actual mesh?

Tags: modeling, faces

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.skillshare.com/classes/Blender-3D-Your-First-3D-Character/527979685?teacherRef=9313365)

In the previous tutorial, we are manipulating the shape of the model using a sort of outline around the mesh itself (box modeling). In the linked tutorial, which is immediately following the previous one, he is going to extrude directly from one of the faces on the mesh, instead of the outline. I am, however, stuck in this outline mode, and I can't figure out how to switch back to selecting anything directly on the mesh.

What he does, or what the program automatically does, to switch back to doing so, is not clear to me, as it seems to just...happen for him. See pictures for visuals. [image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: As @moonboots says we really need to see your blend file, but two comments spring to mind. 1) There's no point posting a link to a paid tutorial because we won't be able to see it, and 2) The Mirror and Subdivision modifiers in your image are reversed. Try dragging the Subdivision modifier down below the Mirror modifier using the little oblong of dots at the right-hand side of the modifier panel. Then click the little computer screen icon on that modifier to disable the view, and reduce the viewort level to 1 to match his settings and see what happens.

Comment: You are in *Face Selection* mode. It's the icons on the top left corner of your screenshot. The tutor is *Edge Selection* mode and he extrudes the edge with key E. You can switch the modes with keys 1, 2 and 3 in *Edit* mode. Press 2 and select the edge, then E to extrude.

Comment: And it looks like you need to add more edge loops to extrude the foot. You can add a loop with Ctrl+R when you have selected an edge or a vertex.